# How to insert multiple rows of data in php msql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am building a php form where users can select many services to offer on their account.

As shown in the attached image, users can select 3 services (each with name and price).

If a is user completing a form, and that user selects services 1, 2 and 3, each service with its own price, how do I insert them into the database each with its own row?

**THIS IS MY CODE** -

But it does not work, it only inserts one row with the last data.

[image]

```
public function insert_data($post_data){      
      extract($post_data);        
     if ($service_1 != '' && $service_1_price != ''){ 
        $artist_services['service_1']    =   $service_1;
        $artist_services['service_1_price']    =   $service_1_price;          
        $artist_services['uid'] = $_SESSION['user_id'];
        $this->db->insert('artist_services', $artist_services);
     }
    if ($service_2 != '' && $service__price != ''){ 
        $artist_services['service_2']    =   $service_2;
        $artist_services['service_1_price']    =   $service_2_price;          
        $artist_services['uid'] = $_SESSION['user_id'];
        $this->db->insert('artist_services', $artist_services);
     }
 }
```

My question is, how do I insert all the services into the MySQL database, each service with its own row?

Comment: you can use insert_batch for inserting multiple record at a time

Comment: Your schema shows `SERVICE` but you're writing `$artist_services['service_1']`. Surely that should be `$artist_services['SERVICE']` to match your schema.

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
if ($service_2 != '' && $service__price != ''){
```

You want:

```
if ($service_2 != '' && $service_2_price != ''){
```

There's also something out of place where you're doing `$artist_services['service_2']` but then `$artist_services['service_1_price']`. But it's not obvious that it should be `service_2_price` there. Wouldn't the database schema just be `service` and `price` without any numbers? That would be typical; having separate columns for different services is almost certainly not what you want.

Comment: Sorry I mis-typed it here. but its correct in my code. So you think that its better to use one row for each user, rather than multiple rows for each user who has multiple services?

Comment: In a normalized database schema, you'll have one row per "thing". So, a user with three services would have three rows, and the field name would be just `service` (not `service_1`)